# Длительность сессии php

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте.

В php файле использую сессии `session_start();`, куки не использую.
Пытаюсь продлить время жизни сессии. Естественно, на хостинге файл php.ini не дают править и советуют все настройки указывать в `.htaccess` там я указал строку равную трем часам `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800`
но сессия все равно обрывается раньше. Может что-то еще нужно прописать?

Comment: С сессиями лучше работать через базу данных, в которой, собственно и хранятся данные сессии. В итоге, время жизни можно оставить по умолчанию, правда одну куку все таки нужно будет сохранить на клиенте, id сессии.

Answer (score 3):

Помимо установки настроек session.gc_maxlifetime и session.cookie_lifetime надо учитывать еще одну тонкость. http://kocherov.net/nyuansyi-rabotyi-php-session-gc_maxlifetime/

Если файлы сессий попадают в общую папку, где работают php скрипты с разными настройками, то будут выполняться самые минимальные настройки из возможных. В этом случае надо хранить файлы сессий в отдельной папке для этого сайта.

`ini_set(‘session.save_path’, value)`

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте добавить в начале скриптов:

```
session_set_cookie_params(86400);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
```

и проверьте, что при вызове phpinfo значение изменилось.

Comment: Да оно изменилось, но у меня два столбца. Local Value и Master Value. Соответственно в Local - 86400 в Master 1440. Он будет брать значение Local получается в приоритете?

Comment: да, но эти строчки необходимо глобально вынести, чтобы они применялись во всех PHP скриптах вашего сайта.

Comment: почему то все равно сессия раньше кончилась

Comment: @Валерий возможно нужно поставить перед стартом сессии ( session_start() ), желательно в самом начале. Либо на вашем хостинге и вовсе подобные настройки не разрешается менять.